# What is a simple expression for $\Phi(p_1)-\Phi(p_0)$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am wondering if there is a simple expression for $\Phi(p_1)-\Phi(p_0)$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution and $p_1$ and $p_0$ are probabilities. I know that generally we can get

$$
\Phi(p_1)-\Phi(p_0)= \Phi(p_0 < x<p_1)
$$

but does there exist a more direct way of expressing it, perhaps allow me to have $p_1$ and $p_0$ in the same expression?

Comment: In terms of length $\Phi(p_1)-\Phi(p_0)$ looks fairly short to me.  Is $\displaystyle \int\limits_{p_0}^{p_1} \phi(x)\, dx$ any better?

Comment: Thank you, that actually really helps. I wanted to originally write something where I could have the probabilities together, like $\Phi(p_1-p_0)$, is there a possible I could reduce what you have $\displaystyle \int\limits_{p_0}^{p_1} \phi(x)\, dx$ to the previously expression or something like it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Psi=\Phi(y)-\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2
   }}\right)\right)$$ Define $z=\frac {x+y}2$ and $\Delta=\frac {y-x}2$ $$\Psi=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{z+\Delta
   }{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{z-\Delta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) $$ Assuming that $\Delta$ is "small", you would make a Taylor expansion and get
$$\Psi=\Delta\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\left(1+\frac{z^2-1}{6} \Delta ^2 +\frac{z^4-6
   z^2+3}{120} \Delta ^4 +O\left(\Delta ^6\right) \right)$$

Using $x=0.6$ and $y=0.8$, the exact value is $0.062397719167$  while the above approximation would give $0.062397719123$.

Play with it and let me know.

**Edit**

If we make it for the full case
$$\Psi=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{y-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)\sim
\Delta\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{   e^{-\frac{(z-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sigma } K$$ where$$K=\left(1+\frac{ (z-\mu )^2-\sigma ^2}{6 \sigma ^4}\Delta ^2+\frac{
   \left(3 \sigma ^4-6 \sigma ^2 (z-\mu )^2+(z-\mu )^4\right)}{120 \sigma
   ^8}\Delta ^4+O\left(\Delta ^6\right) \right)$$